# Valgrind and wildcard?

Tags: valgrind

According to the [valgrind docs](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress):

> Locations may be names of either shared objects, functions, or source lines. They begin with obj:, fun:, or src: respectively. Function, object, and file names to match against may use the wildcard characters * and ?. Source lines are specified using the form filename[:lineNumber].

So `?` counts as a wildcard, but, to match what? I have stackframes like:

```
==60548== Invalid write of size 4
==60548==    by 0x....: ???
==60548==    by 0x....: ???
==60548==    by 0x....: function_signature_2 (in /some/path/libX.so)
==60548==    by 0x....: function_signature_3 (in /some/path/libX.so)
==60548==    by 0x....: function_signature_4 (some_file2:some_line2)
```

and I want to filter those that have `???` in the top of the stack for example. I can write the custom suppression:

```
{
   mysuppression
   Memcheck:Addr4
   obj:???
}
```

and it seems to work nicely, but what exactly does `?`? Matching one single character (and so `obj:???` is matching all objects whose name is 3 chars long?), or marking the previous character as optionally appearing? (in which case, what would `?` as first character mean?), or any other similar meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching is like shell globbing.

`*` matches any number of any character.
`?` matches once any character.

In the log file, `???` means that no function name was found. It doesn’t have any meaning in terms of matching like the suppression syntax.

Comment: Which means that my supression is supressing all stacksframes whose **top frame** comes from **any object** that is 3-chars long right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.